# react-native-fbSDK Sharedialog.show giving empty result when share via FB application but working with fb in app dialog

Tags: react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk, fbsdksharedialog

I am using react-native-fbsdk in my RN app (version "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.10.1",) I am using `ShareDialog.show` method and getting callback and check result, Everything was working fine but when I install FB application and try to share via FB app then getting empty callback result with promise (Either I share or cancel the post). So, I tried with many ways the result is same.

Below is my code

```
  shareLinkWithShareDialog() {
    var tmp = this;
    // If remove below line the code work with in app dialog
    ShareDialog.setMode('native'); 
    ShareDialog.canShow(this.state.shareLinkContent).then(
      function(canShow) {
        if (canShow) {
          return ShareDialog.show(tmp.state.shareLinkContent);
        }
      }
    ).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert('Share cancelled');
        } else {
          alert('Share success with postId: ' + result.postId);
        }
      },
      function(error) {
        alert('Share fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    );
  }
```

So, My question is, How can I get result as I was getting with in-app dialog (When not using `ShareDialog.setMode('native');` line.

UPDATE QUESTION:

Now I am getting callback but always `{isCancelled: true}`. I just update the AppDelegate method and use `return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options]` instant of `return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:nil]`.

Comment: Hello, did you solve this one?